# Dotnet core application deployment

Tags: .net-core

Maybe a silly question, but not clear to me.

If I created a console app on my local machine where I use visual studio 2017 and dotnet was installed via visual studio installer.

So I am presuming with installer the sdk and runtime were installed via the installer.

If I now want to publish the console app to a Windows server machine, what do I need to install?
From reading, but not clear to me, do I just need to install the runtime and not the sdk?

Then to run, I would do dotnet myapp.dll and this would start up app.
If just runtime is their a way to do this in an automated way e.g. powershell script that can do this instead of installer

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli? Did that leave you with more specific questions?

Comment: I have read this, but didn't come across the question I asked which is what do I need installed on my server machine

Comment: For self-contained deployments, nothing. For framework-dependent deployments: "In addition to the application binaries, your installer should also either bundle the shared framework installer or check for it as a prerequisite as part of the application installation."

Comment: Not using self contained. Asking for what I need to install to allow running dotnet core app on Windows server i.e. is it full sdk with cli tools or just runtime which I think( could be wrong) don't have cli tools

Comment: From what I have read, sdk should only be required for development and build server but not to run application, but don't I need cli commands to run, this is where I am confused

Comment: You want to install the runtime (aka shared framework) on the server, then. The runtime comes with the `dotnet` command, which can you use to run your application via something like `dotnet C:\Path\To\Your\Application.dll`.